# Finding new lines in one file compared with another

Tags: files, file-comparison

I need to compare two txt files. Every line of both txt files contain entries. One entry per line. The new file contains entries the old one lacks. I have tried to use `diff` and `vimdiff` but these don't work because the lines may be in different order.

For example:

**OLD FILE**

```
alpha
beta
gama
```

**NEW FILE**

```
delta
omega
beta
alpha
gama
rho
phi
```

`diff` and `vimdiff` compares line 1 with line 1, line 2 with line 2, etc and even if I sort both files the comparison will not succeed because I can have new items between the sorted versions, like  "alpha, beta, rho"  versus "alpha, beta, gama, rho".

How do I get a list of entries that the new file have that the old one does not?

Comment: I don't understand the explanation why `diff` over the sorted files should not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
start cmd:> awk 'FNR == NR { oldfile[$0]=1; }; 
  FNR != NR { if(oldfile[$0]==0) print; }' file1 file2
delta
omega
rho
phi
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `grep`

```
grep -Fxvf oldfile newfile
```

`-F` : use fixed string mode (no metacharacters)

`-x`: match the whole line (not a substring)

`-f oldfile` : read the strings to be matched from `oldfile`

`-v` : invert the match i.e. print strings NOT found in `oldfile`

Answer (score 2):

A shorter `awk` command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

If `file1` can be empty, replace `NR==FNR` with `FILENAME==ARGV[1]`.

`grep -Fxvf file2 file1` is slow for large files:

```
$ jot -r 10000 1 100000 >file1;jot -r 10000 1 100000 >file2
$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2 >/dev/null
0.015
$ time grep -Fxvf file2 file1 >/dev/null
36.758
$ time comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)>/dev/null
0.173
```

If you need to remove repeated lines, use

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!b[$0]++&&!($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

or

```
comm -13 <(sort file1) <(sort -u file2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the order of entries, sort both files and then use [`comm`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/comm.html).

```
comm -13 <(sort old.txt) <(sort new.txt)
```

Or if your shell doesn't have process substitution:

```
sort old.txt >sorted.old.txt
sort new.txt >sorted.new.txt
comm -13 sorted.old.txt sorted.new.txt
```

If the order of entries matters, you can use [`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) with the right options: `-Fx` to match full lines exactly, `-v` to exclude matching lines, and `-f` to read a file containing the patterns to exclude.

```
grep -Fxv -f old.txt new.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need the `python` way of doing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4


oldfp = open('/tmp/tmp.Q3JiYGY6fs/oldfile')
newfp = open('/tmp/tmp.Q3JiYGY6fs/newfile')


old = set([ x.strip() for x in oldfp.readlines() ])
new = set([ x.strip() for x in newfp.readlines() ])

print('Lines that are present only in newfile are \n{}\n\n{} '.format(42*'-', '\n'.join(list(new - old))))
```

And the output will be

```
Lines that are present only in newfile are 
------------------------------------------

phi
rho
omega
delta
```